# How can I check if a table cell is empty or NULL?

Tags: mysql

I select some data from the mySQL database. I want select only the data where project_id is not NULL or empty:

```
$result = $db->query('SELECT * 
         FROM data 
         LEFT JOIN projects ON data.project=projects.project_id
         GROUP BY data.id
         WHERE projects.project_id IS NOT NULL
         ORDER BY data.id DESC
         ')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

but I get an error message:

> Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access
>   violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'WHERE projects.project_id IS NOT NULL ORDER BY d' at line 21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a proper syntax for query as group by will be before than where .
Query should be

```
          SELECT * FROM data 
          LEFT JOIN projects ON data.project=projects.project_id
          WHERE projects.project_id IS NOT NULL
          GROUP BY data.id
          ORDER BY data.id DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

`where` clause comes before `group by`

I believe you are already having primary keys, you don't need to add the `null` check explicitly. If you need the matching dataset only, use `inner join` instead of `left join`.

Comment: Please just vote to close such typo questions if possible.

Comment: A good point for the inner join instead of left join to avoid unnecessary null check

Answer (score 1):

This should work, you are just not following the correct syntax with `where` and `order by`

```
$result = $db->query('SELECT * 
          FROM data 
          LEFT JOIN projects ON data.project=projects.project_id
          WHERE projects.project_id IS NOT NULL
          GROUP BY data.id
          ORDER BY data.id DESC
          ')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```